# Why am i getting more records when using partition by instead of group by+partition by?

Tags: sql, sql-server

As a newcomer i am working on AdventureWorks2014 database and i am trying to get "the latest 3 orders per customer".

```
select CustomerID,
       OrderDate from 
      (select row_number() over(partition by CustomerID 
         order by OrderDate desc) as rownumber,
             CustomerID,
             OrderDate 
             from sales.SalesOrderHeader) as x
                 where rownumber <=3
```

This query gives 28.586 rows as a result.After that i had tried using group by in the same query.

```
   select CustomerID,
          OrderDate from 
          (select row_number() over(partition by CustomerID order by              
            OrderDate desc) as rownumber,
             CustomerID,
             OrderDate 
             from sales.SalesOrderHeader) as x
               where rownumber <=3
               GROUP BY CustomerID,OrderDate
```

But the query which contains GROUP BY operator gives 28.575 rows as a result.I've checked the first and last customers and it was all the same.
Now here is the question; What is causing this? Why GROUP BY clause reduces the total rows showed in results?Which query gives the true result?

Comment: Can you post SQL in text instead of screenshot? It may help others to read and analyze.

Comment: why you don't post sql as text?

Comment: I guess you have a doubled up record which you remove by using the group by.  here is why the group by removes records http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because some orders are in same date.
You can find it by add `HAVING Count(1) > 1` to query with `Group By`